# padding is not used in ie7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I used a padding in select list of gender but its not working in ie7.
its working properly in all browser ie8, firefox, safari but not working
in iee7 i tried a lot but nothing happened...

```
<div class="clear" style="margin-top:5px; float:left; text-align:right">
                          <% @sex = [['male', '0'],['female', '1'], ['others', '2']] %> 
                          <%= select_tag :sex,
options_for_select(@sex), :style=>"padding-left:15px; width:100px;
height:30px;padding-left:15px;vertical-align:middle;" %>
</div>
```

Thanks
Mayur Mate

Comment: It may be useful to include how you're styling "clear" classes in from your stylesheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add display: inline-block in your div and use a proper DOCTYPE such as

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```