# Padding on select not working in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

This is my HTML:

```
<SELECT> 
    <OPTION selected value=1>Date</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=2>Instrument ID</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=3>Efile ID</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
select
{
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: "open sans", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Verdana, 
                  Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Could anybody please tell me why is padding on select not working in IE7? It seems to be working in IE8, 9, FFX 11 and above and Chrome too.

Comment: You still have to support IE7?

Comment: yes :( else why would I post this question ;)

Comment: No padding doesn't work on IE and Firefox!

Comment: I would try wrapping the `<select>` box in a `div` and give the div ( which would be considered the parent` a padding of whatever you desire.

Comment: possible duplicate of [padding is not used in ie7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947656/padding-is-not-used-in-ie7)

Comment: @RPM: Good suggestion however I'd like to avoid that as long as I find something without using any wrapper because this will be a big cost. I will have to hunt for each dropdown and wrap it in div.

Comment: @RPM: according to gstatcounter, IE7, at 0.81% usage, has an bigger market share than IE10...

Answer (score 0):

#### You need to give a `DOCTYPE`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

#### And also, give this CSS:

```
select {display: inline; zoom: 1;}
```

---

#### Another option is to use [jNice](http://www.whitespace-creative.com/jquery/jNice/).

---

#### Another Idea:

Wrap the `select` with `label` and style the `label` by giving the `border` to it.

Comment: didn't work. I already had DocType and I tried adding zoom:1 and display. Same result. By the way I am into Developer tools (F12) in IE9 and selected IE7.

Comment: Ah... I am in the same thing. Try using jNice: http://www.whitespace-creative.com/jquery/jNice/

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Do you have an incentive for suggesting the OP use jNice?

Comment: LOL, I know how cruel it is to maintain compatibility for IE, I am a front end engineer too. So, you see... `:)` *I know that feel, bro!*

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select
{
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px !important;
    font-family: "open sans", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Verdana, 
                  Arial, sans-serif;
}
```